# GridFS with pymongo cannot retrieve files

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, gridfs

I tried to test GridFS and I cannot get past this:
I've put a file into a local gridfs.

```
$ mongofiles list
connected to: 127.0.0.1
IMGP2224.JPG     1125745
```

in the code I have:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import gridfs
...
def index():
     db = MongoClient('localhost', 27017).gridfs
     files = gridfs.GridFS(db)
     image = files.list()
     import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
     **pdb here gives empty []**
     return render_template("index.html", images=image)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't provide a database name when you use `mongofiles` it will use the default database (which is called `test`).   If you don't specify a collection name, it will use `fs.files` and `fs.chunks`.

So in your Python code you need to use `test` as the database name, instead of gridfs and then it will find your default `fs.files` and `fs.chunks` collections.

Comment: well still, I'm getting a list that's ok. in mongo shell in test db: db.fs.files.find() gives {"_id": ObjectId("5287b92d53aad8ef5062a08c", "filename" : "IMGP2224.JPG".......} 
but in python code:
files.exists(filename="IMGP2224.JPG")
True
files.get("5287b92d53aad8ef5062a08c")
NoFile: no file in gridfs collection

Comment: Don't do: files.get("5287b92d53aad8ef5062a08c"). Do: files.get(ObjectId("5287b92d53aad8ef5062a08c")). ObjectIds and strings are different from each other.